# Start up a Spring web application project using Maven and ReactJS under Intellij Idea

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am a beginner to Spring and I would like to set up a full stack RestFul project using `Maven, ReactJS`. I am stuck with where should I begin with since I browse Spring website and they provide both `Spring` and `Spring boot`.

Could someone tell me how can I set up an easy example using `Spring + Maven + ReactJS`.

I appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot is Spring + **High Productivity Boost**. You can fork and (or) check out this [excellent Spring boot + ReactJs webapp example](https://github.com/winterbe/spring-react-example) from github and follow the tutorial [here](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/02/16/isomorphic-react-webapps-on-the-jvm/). If you want to learn more about the various features of spring boot, see its section on [spring io website](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

Comment: Thanks very much for that and this is I am looking for.

Comment: You are welcome @Guifan Li and if my answer is usefull don't forget to upvote it or accept it so that others can find it too

Comment: Your link is broken.